# Map function seems to not execute?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a test for a function that utilizes a simple validation function. My function needs to validate all the incoming parameters. The validation function throws an `AttributeError` when there is a problem and returns True otherwise. However, when I map `validate` it doesn't work unless I do something additional, like use `all()`:

```
def my_function(a, b, c=None):
    map(validate, (a, b, c))  # This doesn't fail validation (incorrect behavior)
    all(map(validate, (a, b, c))  # This DOES fail validation (correct behavior)
    # Some other stuff
```

My unit test does this:

```
def test_my_function(self):
    bad_id = 0
    self.assertRaises(AttributeError, add_favorite, 10, bad_id)
```

And this is my validation function:

```
def validate(identifier):
    if identifier is None:
        return True
    elif not isinstance(identifier, int):
        raise AttributeError("Identifier={0} not of type integer.".format(identifier))
    elif not (identifier > 0):
        raise AttributeError("Identifier={0} not an integer greater than zero.".format(identifier))
    else:
        return True
```

I am confused why `map` doesn't seem to execute unless I wrap it in something else: I've confirmed it doesn't execute by running the test via debug and seeing that it never enters `validate()`. (I see no point in doing additional work that is thrown out...) According to the [documentation](http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php) it seems as though map *should* be iterating over those params and executing the function. Can someone explain why it doesn't?

EDIT: Correct [documentation](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_lambda.php) shows that map returns a lazily evaluated iterator.

Comment: You've tagged the question with `python-3.x` and you're pointing at tutorial suited for Python 2. Which one do you use? Behavior of `map` function differs between these two. I.e., in 3.x `map` returns iterator and it won't execute your `validate` function unless you start, well, iterating this iterator: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map] .

Comment: Really, there are very few cases where you need to use `map` in modern python. If you care about the resultant list, a list-comprehension (EX: `[validate(item) for item in (a,b,c)]`) is faster, and if you don't, a `for` loop doesn't waste a list allocation. Having said that, the reason it fails is that `map` in 3.x returns an `iterator` that needs evaluation (which the `all` does) whereas the 2.x version does not.

Comment: Ah, yes! I had thought I was on the 3.x documentation, but I wasn't. I see now the details about the iterator. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python 3.x, `map` creates an iterable.  Iterables are evaluated lazily - that is, only the elements you iterate over (such as looping over them) are actually evaluated.  In your example, since you don't iterate over any values, none of the values get evaluated.  In the `any` case, however, `any` iterates over the entire result `map`, so the whole thing gets evaluated.

It is a bit more complicated, since there are other ways to evaluate parts of an iterable without iterating over them (such as using `next()` to evaluate and get just the next item), but for your purposes this is close enough.

So these get evaluated:

```
all(map(validate, (a, b, c))
list(map(validate, (a, b, c)))
[_ for x in map(validate, (a, b, c))]
a = map(validate, (a, b, c);all(a)
b = map(validate, (a, b, c));list(b)
```

Note that in the last two cases, the iterable is not evaluated until the `all(a)` or `list(a)` is called.  This could be many lines later in the code, in another function, and/or in another module.

Further, the iterable only evaluates one step at a time.  Consider this example:

```
for x in map(validate, (a, b, c)):
    print(x)
```

It will run `validate` on the first item, put into into x, then run through the body of the loop.  Once the first run of the loop is done, only then will it evaluated the second item, then run through the body of the loop again, then evaluate the next item, and so on.  If you break the loop, the remaining items will not be evaluated.

These do not get evaluated:

```
map(validate, (a, b, c)
a = map(validate, (a, b, c)
(_ for x in map(validate, (a, b, c)))
```